# Sitecore OpenGraphs Meta Tags rendered in body

Tags: sxa

Sitecore OpenGraphs Meta Tags rendered in body in html,
[image]

and I need to render these meta tags in "head", Note: Open Garaph rendering in Metadata partial design in head placeholder

[image]

so is there another thing should i do to render the tags in head???

Comment: In final layout, check whether the open graph rendering is inserted in the "head" placeholder. You can also verify the layout whether the head placeholder is called in the right place or not..

Comment: I checked the final layout and also open graph rendering inserted in the "head" placeholder, but I do not know how can i check the head placeholder is called in the right place or not??

Comment: You can check the layout which is present inside the Sitecore instance view folder. The Path is '/Views/SxaLayout/SxaLayout.cshtml'

Comment: The head placeholder which is @Html.Sxa().Placeholder("head"), should be called inside <head> </head> tags. By default, it is called inside this location. You can verify once

Answer (score 2):

This will happen when the placeholder is not listed in the placeholders excluded from the experience accelerator grid.

When SXA upgraded to a Bootstrap 4 grid, it needed to make sure that all placeholders were wrapped in a `div` with a class of `row` so that the column classes would work on child components. This means that any placeholder will have that.

If that `div` gets added to the placeholders in the `<head>` area, the dev tools in Chrome will show them in the `<body>` section. If you view the source you will see them in the right place, but wrapped in a `<div class="row"></div>`.

To prevent this, there is a setting for all the placeholders that shouldn't have the wrapping `div`:

```
<experienceAccelerator>
    <grid>
        <placeholderWrapper>
            <excludedPlaceholders>
                <placeholder>Placeholder Key</placeholder>
            </excludedPlaceholders>
        </placeholderWrapper>
    </grid>
</experienceAccelerator>
```

In the default, this list *should* contain the `head` placeholder key. But if you try to patch this and don't patch it correctly it can remove the default list and replace it with only the ones in your patch file.

Take the above example, if you used that as your patch, it will remove all existing keys. You need to make sure your new key is patched to a location like this:

```
<placeholder patch:before="placeholder[0]">Placeholder Key</placeholder>
```

Make sure you can see the `head` placeholder key in that list, use the `/sitecore/admin/showConfig.aspx` page. Your list should look like this:

```
<placeholderWrapper patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.config">
    <excludedPlaceholders>
        <placeholder>head</placeholder>
        <placeholder>sxa-metadata-partial-design</placeholder>
        <placeholder>sxa-header</placeholder>
        <placeholder>sxa-footer</placeholder>
        <placeholder>sxa-main</placeholder>
        <placeholder>body-top</placeholder>
        <placeholder>body-bottom</placeholder>
    </excludedPlaceholders>
</placeholderWrapper>
```

If it doesn't, that is your problem. Figure out what is removing that list.